# Using JavaScript in Vaadin Java Application

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I want to use the Kurento WebRTC javascript client in my Java web application.

But I even cant manage to call a simple javascript function in my Java application. What am I missing?

```
var connector = this;

connector.test = function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
}
```

Here comes the Java Code:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent;


@JavaScript({"rtc.js", "jquery-1.12.3.min.js"})
public class VideoCall extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

    public VideoCall() {

    }

    public void testMethod() {
        callFunction("test");
        //Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("alert('Hello world!')");
        System.out.println("testMethod executed!");
    }

}
```

When I uncommend

```
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("alert('Hello world!')");
```

I get a window with the message "Hello world!". When I change test to foo as argument in callFunction I dont get an error message, although foo doesnt exist as function. 
Why does the code not work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first code snippet you've shown there is the `rtc.js` file that you include using `@JavaScript`. What's missing from that file is that it should register itself as a connector for that particular Java class.

The file should look like this:

```
window.java_package_name_VideoCall = function() {
  var connector = this;

  connector.test = function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
  }
}
```

where `java_package_name` is the the package name of the `VideoCall` class with `.` replaced with `_`.

Comment: Thx Leif, but still not working. Something else must be missing.

Comment: Really hard to help debug anything without further details. I would recommend that you check for errors in the Console or Network sections in the browser's developer tools, and in Vaadin's debug window that is opened if you add `?debug` to the URL.